# Error: "object 'output' not found" or "Error in eval_tidy: object 'input' not found" when writing subprocesses in different Shiny scripts

Tags: r, shiny, scope, shinydashboard

I've written down many different shiny apps which I want to unite in one single shiny app, accesing to them through the menus of the `shinydashboard`

I dont want to write them all in one single sript. I'd like to write every different app in different script and then just source them all in one `Main.R` script.

The problem is that I get Errors like

`Error in eval_tidy: object 'input' not found` or

`Error in output$name= renderText({ : object 'output' not found`

**Main.R**

has the following code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

### --- Header
Header = dashboardHeader(title = "Test")

source(file = "sub2.R", local = TRUE) # <- source the next app code

### ---- Menu and subMenu

subItem1 = menuSubItem(tabName = "sub1", text = "First subItem") # <- first subprocess

Menu1 = menuItem(text = "Test app", 
                 subItem1
                 ,subItem2 # <- sourced from sub2.R
                 ) 

Menu = sidebarMenu(Menu1) 

SideBar = dashboardSidebar(Menu) # Only menus in the sideBar

Tab_sub1 = tabItem(tabName = "sub1",    # <- this is the first app process
                   fluidPage(
                     actionButton(inputId = "run_sub1", label = "Run"),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')", tags$div('Please wait 5 seconds ... ')),
                     textOutput(outputId = "timer_sub1")
                   ))


Tabs = tabItems(Tab_sub1     # <- App 1 (in main) and app 2 tabs
                ,Tab_sub2) # <- this is called from source sub2.R

Body = dashboardBody(Tabs)

ui = dashboardPage(header = Header,
                   sidebar = SideBar,
                   body = Body,
                   skin = "red")

######  ------------ Server
server = function(input, output, session){
  
  source(file = "sub2.R", local = TRUE) # <- call the second App
  
  Memory_sub1 = reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$run_sub1,{
    
    Memory_sub1$timerStart = proc.time()
    
    Sys.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds
    
    Memory_sub1$timerEnd = proc.time() 
    
  })
  
  
  output$timer_sub1 = renderText({
    Memory_sub1$timerEnd[3]- Memory_sub1$timerStart[3]
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This part works fine alone. The app just waits 5 seconds when you hit the button and returns the wait time.

**sub2.R**

This code does the exact same thing as the main part, but it returns two kinds of errors.

With everything as it is returns `Error in output$timer_sub2 = renderText({ : object 'output' not found`

if I comment the `output$timer_sub2` part of the code it then returns `Warning: Error in eval_tidy: object 'input' not found` (this still shows up the app though)

This is the code:

```
### ------ Ui part
subItem2 = menuSubItem(tabName = "sub2", text = "Second subItem")



Tab_sub2 = tabItem(tabName = "sub2",
                   fluidPage(
                     actionButton(inputId = "run_sub2", label = "Run"),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')", tags$div('Please wait 5 seconds ... ')),
                     textOutput(outputId = "timer_sub2")
                   ))



### -------- Server part
Memory_sub2 = reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$run_sub2,{
  
  Memory_sub2$timerStart = proc.time()
  
  Sys.sleep(5)
  
  Memory_sub2$timerEnd = proc.time()  
  
})


output$timer_sub2 = renderText({
  Memory_sub2$timerEnd[3]- Memory_sub2$timerStart[3]
})
```

Obviously this might not be the way to achive what I want. Could some one tell me how? I was expecting to have the UI and Server part of the apps in their own script and then source them in the main script but I get this errors... Is it even posible what I want to achieve?

Comment: I also encountered the same problem, do you got any solution? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote my solution below. The ui and the server must be in different scripts, not in the same one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had the `ui` and the `server` in one single script **sub2.R** ... They must be sepparated in differents scripts... i.e. **"ui sub2.R"** and **"server sub2.R"**...